# MonetDB insert wrong data

Tags: monetdb

please help

One of tables in database starts inserting wrong data. I'm doing simple

```
insert into operator_poll(operator_id, poll_id, activity_id) values (1,2,3);
```

and got

```
+-------------+---------+----------------------------+-------------+
| operator_id | poll_id | time                       | activity_id |
+=============+=========+============================+=============+
|           1 |    1010 | 2018-06-01 09:53:22.000000 |           1 |
+-------------+---------+----------------------------+-------------+
```

before that I was importing a lot data in this table may be it has some cache?

My version of Monet is Jul2017-SP2

Comment: Hi @redexp. Could you please show the definition of the operator_poll table? (you can use the \d directive in mclient to do so). 

Also please be aware that 2 bug-fix and 1 feature release have been published since Jul2017-SP2, and generally we suggest frequent upgrades to new releases.

Comment: @PanagiotisKoutsourakis before this bug I inserted lot of data (like 60 000 rows) through nodejs lib by 100 rows per request. And now it looks like on each insert to this table Monet takes data from cache and not inserts actual data. Fixed it with copying all data to new table, remove old one and copy data to one more new table with old name